# Google Maps API V3 same event lister to multiple arrays of markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

So basically I have something like this

```
var arrayOfMarker1 = [...], arrayOfMarker2 = [...], ... arrayOfMarkerN = [...];
```

and I want to use a eventListener able to close the current open infoPanel to show the last clicked one, even if it is a marker of another array to be clicked.

Example:

- I open a marker of arrayOfMarker1 infoPanel (let's call it **marker1**)
- I click on a arrayOfMarker2 marker (**marker2**)
- **marker1**'s infoPanel is closed and **marker2**'s in opened

The only thing that I have found is this

```
marker.addListener('click', function () {
    infowindow.setContent(this.html);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
});
```

But it just works for markers of the same array. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need a global variable to track the last opened infoPanel.

```
var openedInfoWindow = null;
marker.addListener('click', function () {
    if(openedInfoWindow != null)
    {
        openedInfoWindow.close();
    }
    openedInfoWindow = infowindow;
    infowindow.setContent(this.html);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
});
```